# Comparing different scenarios for DC-DC power delivery between two PCBs

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, dc-dc-converter

For my robotics project, I am dealing with a system that is broken up into different components, that are mechanically decoupled (a head and torso part, connected via a multi-wire cable). I want to deliver power and data to the head through the body, using a LiPo battery. I am trying to come up with the optimal design, but I am running into some challenges that I could not overcome yet. The goal and circumstances can be summarized as:

- The head part contains several power hungry devices that have a variable current consumption, including a Raspberry Pi 4, several motors to control head movement, sensors, RGB LEDs, and two amplifier IC's + speakers for audio
- *All current values are absolute maximums*, as provided by the datasheets
- To support the Raspberry Pi 5 in the future, I am taking into account the 5V 5A power supply requirement
- I am desiging two PCB's to handle power delivery, one for the head, and one for the body. I have full freedom over how these PCB's handle the power delivery. The head PCB will deliver power directly to the Raspberry Pi.
- I am trying to keep the supply voltage high, to reduce the current required through the cable, as there is not much space for big cables, and bigger cables would impair the movement of the head part. I currently have a 5S LiPo in mind to find balance between current through wires, and voltage regulator efficiency.
- Space in the head component is limited, so I am going for small PCB footprints where possible
- The power cable I have in mind is rated to deliver ~1,25A per wire, with 4 V+ wires, and 4 GND wires. Two remaining wires are used for I2C (SCL/SDA).

I can summarize the expected absolute maximum power requirements for the head component per voltage as follows, with an absolute maximum of 57W (but nominal consumption would be much lower):
[image: Current and power per voltage]

The scenarios I had in mind are listed below:

- Power should go from PCB 1 to PCB 2
- **>** arrow indicates a DC-DC voltage conversion
- In all scenario's, PCB 1 is connected to PCB 2 using the mentioned power/data cable.

[image: Scenarios]

To provide power to the head, I see several possibilities, each with their own limitation. Is there any advice on which scenario would work best? With my current knowledge, scenario 3 would make the most sense since it transmits power at a higher voltage (and thus lower current to provide the same amount of power), putting less temperature increase on the cable, and then converting it to the required voltages on PCB 2. Am I thinking in the right direction with this approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use a linear regulator for such a high load. You'll end up wasting a ton of space and money on heatsinks. When you say "power delivery", you're not referring to the USB Power Delivery standard are you? Because you don't seem to have anything related to the standard here.

Comment: I was actually considering using the USB-C Power Delivery standard (not explicitly mentioned), hence the conversion to 20V in scenario 1 and 2, but that would increase the complexity and BOM price of the project. If justified, I would actually consider it since the USB-C standard delivers everything I need. The I2C connection can easily be dropped for USB instead, as both PCB's will have a RP2040 on it to exchange data.

And regarding the linear regulator, do you mean the LDO in scenario 1? In the example I use a small part of the 5V buck output to make 3,3V, is it bad practice?

Comment: Well, for one thing, that will increase the demand on your 5 V regulator; you'll need 6 A, not 5--the extra current for the 3.3 V rail needs to come from somewhere. For another, you'll still be wasting a lot of power (1.7 W, here) that will need to be dissipated somehow. A switching converter would be more efficient, and you always want to be as efficient as possible when using a battery as your power source. This is also why I would go with options 3 or 4; the initial conversion to 20 V is just an extra step you'll lose efficiency in, if not required for anything.

Comment: Also note that using USB PD would require that you have a 5 V converter on PCB 1 as well as a second one on PCB 2; PD requires that you supply 5 V until negotiation agrees on a higher voltage. This would significantly complicate matters, and I don't recommend it for this project.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I think that would make scenario 3 preferrable, where the conversion happens on PCB 2, and PCB 1 only forwards the LiPo power. Am I correct to assume that having a relatively high voltage from the LiPo battery will make the power transfer through the wires require less current, and thus will produce less heat within the cable? (e.g. when using a 5S LiPo vs a 3S LiPo)

Comment: Yes, using a higher voltage reduces the current needed for the same power, but note that this is only true if you use switching converters!

Comment: That is indeed the plan! I am planning on using the TI Webench power designer to provide a setup that will cover the requirements